# How can i create dynamic delete method in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

in codeigniter i can set method for dynamic delete like this code.in laravel how can i set this method for dynamic delete method.Thanks

in controller function

```
public function Delete($id)
{
    if ($this->process_model->DynamicDelete($id, "interest_statement")) {
        //
    }
}
```

in model function

```
public function DynamicDelete($id, $table)
{
    $this->db->delete($table, ['id' => $id]);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any models set up in your laravel app? Is there anything you've tried so far?

Comment: i have a model set up.but i am not trying with model

Comment: In that case @Khang's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use route as like below:

```
Route::get('yourroute/{info}','Yourcontrolller@Yourmethod');
```

and use this route in view page where from request get:

```
{{ URL::to('/yourroute/'.$id.'&your_table')}}
```

and finally you write a function in your controller

```
public function Yourmethod($info){
  $explode=explode('&',$info);
DB::table($explode[1])->where('id',$explode[0])->delete();    
        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Your Data Delete Successfully');
        return back();
```

}

Thank you

Comment: It would be easier to setup the route to get both vars for you `Route::get('yourroute/{table}/{id}', 'Controller@method');` then the you wouldn't need to deal with the vars;

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, you can use Raw Query (Database: Query Builder)

Example:

- Table: users
- Condition: votes > 100

> DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->delete();

In your case:

> public function DynamicDelete($id, $table) {
>
> ```
> return DB::table($table)->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
> ```
>
> }